# Hide error message

Tags: runtime-error, autohotkey

I'm working on an application and am using UDFs (User-Defined-Function) from another script.

When starting my application, AHK throws an error sometimes, reminding me that there is an error in the UDF script (although there isn't).

If I restart my application however the error is gone and the application works normally. How can I make sure that this error messagebox doesn't show up? I don't want the user to be able to view the code of the UDF or any code for that matter.

Is `#Warn All, Off` a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

[#Warn](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Warn.htm) gives you warnings that are *sometimes overzealous*, and it exists *solely for **debugging** purposes*.

It is certainly a good practice to comment it out as soon as you're done debugging the script before releasing it to the users and maybe later uncomment it when you suspect a modification might have introduced possible issues and need to debug.